# How can I disable the DNS that Network Manager uses?

Tags: network-manager, dnsmasq

Ubuntu uses a DNSMasq instance for Network Manager starting in 12.04 - how can I disable it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` with the following command:

`gksu gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Enter in your password when prompted.

Comment out the line `dns=dnsmasq`, so it looks like this:

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

and then restart Network Manager with

```
sudo restart network-manager
# if you get /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused, try:
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Ta-da! You're all set!

Comment: Our entire office is cloud hosted. Some stuff is on a private cloud in AWS with a VPN. dnsmasq was getting in the way of correct DNS resolution when on the VPN. I am the only linux user in the office and everyone else was mac. When I looked at a friends settings on his mac that's when it occurred to me what must be happing. I shut this off and life is good.

Comment: On  Debian Bullseye my configuration required that I restart NetworkManager this way; systemctl restart NetworkManager YMMV

Answer (score 2):

If this still does not work for you, like was my case with Ubuntu 16.10.
Then check who is using this port with:

```
lsof -i :53
```

And if you for example have "systemd-r", then you have to stop the service with:

```
sudo service systemd-resolved stop
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem, but I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, so the original solution did not work. However, [this page](https://superuser.com/questions/1318220/ubuntu-18-04-disable-dnsmasq-base-and-enable-full-dnsmasq) had the solution.

Add `DNSStubListener=no` in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf and then restart the systemd-resolved service. Now, the built-in dnsmasq should not start automatically.

You will also need to make sure that `dns=dnsmasq` is commented out in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf, like the previous answer specifies.