# How to change default dns server

Tags: dns

I am new to ubuntu. When I use the following command 
nslookup askubuntu.com it gives following output:

Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   askubuntu.com
Address: 198.252.206.24

My question is why it is showing my IP address as default DNS server. Does ubuntu contain any DNS service by default. How I can change the default DNS server.

Answer (score 2):

I think network-manager uses **dnsmasq** as local *DNS server*. So that's why it is showing your *localhost* IP as DNS server.

To change that, look at [How can I disable the DNS that Network Manager uses?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233222/how-can-i-disable-the-dns-that-network-manager-uses)

This local DNS server (dnsmasq) will use your router DNS server if you use *dhcp* or whatever DNS server is configured in the router (dhcp) configuration.

Comment: thanks solsTiCe If dnsmasq is local DNS serer then disabling it should result in dns query failure. Why nslookup still showing my IP address

Comment: If Ip of a domain cache in dnsmasq cache is changed but dnsmasq cache entry is not expired what will happen.