# restart network-manager

Tags: network-manager, restart

I followed the steps provided in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/233223/379395). However, one of the steps is to restart the network manager:

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

If I try this I will get the following error message:

```
$ sudo restart network-manager
restart: Verbindung zu Upstart nicht möglich: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
```

[English version below]

```
$ sudo restart network-manager
restart: Connection to Upstart impossible: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

How do I restart the network manager?

Comment: English, please. Do `sudo LANG=C restart network-manager`.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @muru It looks like not 15.04 with systemd.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can restart it by

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Which will in turn call the `initctl` command, for which `restart` is an alias.

Comment: does `reboot ` necessary  or not here?

Comment: No, not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

there is a bug when restarting NM: Network Manager and/or nm-applet forgets its Wired connection and recreates a new connection on each restart

so if you tweak your Ethernet for example set IPv6 to Ignore or modified WoL settings MTU settings etc- you will have to do that again !