# Wifi disappears and starts working only after restart

Tags: wireless

So I've connected to my wifi and to VPN. Sometimes WIFI disappears for couple of seconds and internet stops working. It continues working after restarting a computer.

Is there any way to "reload" the wifi instead of restarting a computer?

Comment: service network-manager restart https://askubuntu.com/questions/675648/restart-network-manager

Comment: @JDas This command doesn't do the trick. My wifi icon just goes black with a question mark inside it and after writing this command, internet doesn't start working, I need to restart a computer.

Answer (score 0):

okay. Try this instead

1> Reboot your system
2> open terminal and use this

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager`

3> `sudo service network-manager restart`

or reboot your system