# Ubuntu 16.04: curl, wget, ssh could not resolve host from dnsmasq with IPv6

Tags: network-manager, wget, ipv6, curl, dnsmasq

Spent a lot of time googling for the problem but did not found answer for it.

Given: fresh Ubuntu 16.04 installation, which implies IPv6 is enabled and network-manager service is using dnsmasq for local DNS caching.

The problem is that for particular domains command line utilities are not resolving host name.

```
$ curl -v https://deb.nodesource.com/
* Could not resolve host: deb.nodesource.com
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: deb.nodesource.com

$ wget http://deb.nodesource.com/
--2017-04-10 15:23:34--  http://deb.nodesource.com/
Resolving deb.nodesource.com (deb.nodesource.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘deb.nodesource.com’

$ ssh deb.nodesource.com
ssh: Could not resolve hostname deb.nodesource.com: Name or service not known
```

While other "common" hosts are working well.

```
$ curl http://www.google.com/
<HTML>...</HTML>
```

Also local DNS cache is working correctly.

```
$ dig deb.nodesource.com   
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> deb.nodesource.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55668
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 9, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 12    
<...>
;; ANSWER SECTION:
deb.nodesource.com. 101 IN  CNAME   d2buw04m05mirl.cloudfront.net.
d2buw04m05mirl.cloudfront.net. 59 IN    A   54.192.98.17
<...>
;; Query time: 38 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Apr 10 15:28:57 EEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 615

$ dig AAAA deb.nodesource.com
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> AAAA deb.nodesource.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52753
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 9, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 12
<...>
;; ANSWER SECTION:
deb.nodesource.com. 300 IN  CNAME   d2buw04m05mirl.cloudfront.net.
d2buw04m05mirl.cloudfront.net. 60 IN    AAAA    2600:9000:203b:9200:1f:6523:6040:93a1
<...>
;; Query time: 58 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Apr 10 15:32:53 EEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 711
```

IPv6 requests are also working:

```
$ dig -6 deb.nodesource.com    
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> -6 deb.nodesource.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5056
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 9, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 12
<...>
;; ANSWER SECTION:
deb.nodesource.com. 290 IN  CNAME   d2buw04m05mirl.cloudfront.net.
d2buw04m05mirl.cloudfront.net. 60 IN    A   54.192.229.174
<...>
;; Query time: 21 msec
;; SERVER: ::1#53(::1)
;; WHEN: Mon Apr 10 16:05:52 EEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 615
```

---

The trick is that if I enforce IPv4 for curl or wget, then it does the trick.

```
$ curl -4 http://deb.nodesource.com/
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

$ wget -4 http://deb.nodesource.com/
--2017-04-10 15:40:28--  http://deb.nodesource.com/
Resolving deb.nodesource.com (deb.nodesource.com)... 54.192.98.73, 54.192.98.106, 54.192.98.122, ...
Connecting to deb.nodesource.com (deb.nodesource.com)|54.192.98.73|:80... connected.
<...>
2017-04-10 15:40:29 (175 KB/s) - ‘index.html.1’ saved [83983]
```

As you can see, local DNS cache supports both IPv4 and IPv6 requests and returns valid answers as well. But I don't understand what prevents all these command line utilities from resolving the host, event if by default system tries to work on IPv6.

Some proposals I found so far:

- to disable IPv6 completely: [How to disable IPv6 in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440649/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-14-04)
- to  disable local DNS cache (dnsmasq) and add manual `nameserver 8.8.8.8`: [How can I disable the DNS that Network Manager uses?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233222/how-can-i-disable-the-dns-that-network-manager-uses)

I would be thankful for any help how to get these features working together.

Thanks!

---

Relevant configs and outputs:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu-host

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

nameserver 127.0.1.1

$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf 
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf 
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis

$ sudo tcpdump port 53
# curl -4 request
15:55:27.161321 IP 192.168.2.101.54124 > 192.168.2.1.domain: 32338+ A? deb.nodesource.com. (36)
15:55:27.184442 IP 192.168.2.1.domain > 192.168.2.101.54124: 32338 9/13/5 CNAME d2buw04m05mirl.cloudfront.net., A 54.192.229.151, A 54.192.229.174, A 54.192.229.177, A 54.192.229.185, A 54.192.229.62, A 54.192.229.76, A 54.192.229.81, A 54.192.229.98 (508)

# curl -6 request
15:57:17.283919 IP 192.168.2.101.54124 > 192.168.2.1.domain: 63423+ A? deb.nodesource.com. (36)
15:57:17.283950 IP 192.168.2.101.54124 > 192.168.2.1.domain: 4140+ AAAA? deb.nodesource.com. (36)
15:57:17.323109 IP 192.168.2.1.domain > 192.168.2.101.54124: 4140| 9/12/0 CNAME d2buw04m05mirl.cloudfront.net., AAAA 2600:9000:203b:8400:1f:6523:6040:93a1, AAAA 2600:9000:203b:da00:1f:6523:6040:93a1, AAAA 2600:9000:203b:f400:1f:6523:6040:93a1, AAAA 2600:9000:203b:2400:1f:6523:6040:93a1, AAAA 2600:9000:203b:2a00:1f:6523:6040:93a1, AAAA 2600:9000:203b:4600:1f:6523:6040:93a1, AAAA 2600:9000:203b:6000:1f:6523:6040:93a1, AAAA 2600:9000:203b:7800:1f:6523:6040:93a1 (508)
15:57:17.323132 IP 192.168.2.1.domain > 192.168.2.101.54124: 63423 9/13/5 CNAME d2buw04m05mirl.cloudfront.net., A 54.192.229.151, A 54.192.229.174, A 54.192.229.177, A 54.192.229.185, A 54.192.229.62, A 54.192.229.76, A 54.192.229.81, A 54.192.229.98 (508)
15:57:17.323683 IP 192.168.2.101.58769 > 192.168.2.1.domain: Flags [S], seq 783238377, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4431703 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:57:17.325295 IP 192.168.2.1.domain > 192.168.2.101.58769: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 783238378, win 0, length 0
15:57:17.325933 IP 192.168.2.101.60649 > 192.168.2.1.domain: Flags [S], seq 665587122, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4431704 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:57:17.331301 IP 192.168.2.1.domain > 192.168.2.101.60649: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 665587123, win 0, length 0
15:57:17.331540 IP 192.168.2.101.54124 > 192.168.2.1.domain: 29050+ A? deb.nodesource.com. (36)
15:57:17.331578 IP 192.168.2.101.54124 > 192.168.2.1.domain: 5852+ AAAA? deb.nodesource.com. (36)
15:57:17.334915 IP 192.168.2.1.domain > 192.168.2.101.54124: 29050 9/13/5 CNAME d2buw04m05mirl.cloudfront.net., A 54.192.229.98, A 54.192.229.151, A 54.192.229.174, A 54.192.229.177, A 54.192.229.185, A 54.192.229.62, A 54.192.229.76, A 54.192.229.81 (508)
15:57:17.334969 IP 192.168.2.1.domain > 192.168.2.101.54124: 5852| 9/12/0 CNAME d2buw04m05mirl.cloudfront.net., AAAA 2600:9000:203b:7800:1f:6523:6040:93a1, AAAA 2600:9000:203b:8400:1f:6523:6040:93a1, AAAA 2600:9000:203b:da00:1f:6523:6040:93a1, AAAA 2600:9000:203b:f400:1f:6523:6040:93a1, AAAA 2600:9000:203b:2400:1f:6523:6040:93a1, AAAA 2600:9000:203b:2a00:1f:6523:6040:93a1, AAAA 2600:9000:203b:4600:1f:6523:6040:93a1, AAAA 2600:9000:203b:6000:1f:6523:6040:93a1 (508)
15:57:17.335550 IP 192.168.2.101.38257 > 192.168.2.1.domain: Flags [S], seq 2283847070, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4431706 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:57:17.336614 IP 192.168.2.1.domain > 192.168.2.101.38257: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 2283847071, win 0, length 0
15:57:17.336763 IP 192.168.2.101.42479 > 192.168.2.1.domain: Flags [S], seq 3878661065, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4431707 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:57:17.337800 IP 192.168.2.1.domain > 192.168.2.101.42479: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 3878661066, win 0, length 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the root cause of the problem: it is my WiFi router.

Despite the fact that `dig` works fine, for some reason command line utilities which are using `getaddrinfo` are not able to parse router's DNS answer (which in my case were proxied by `dnsmasq`).

I have pointed `dnsmasq` to DNS server of my ISP directly, and it worked fine. For some reason my router is corrupting DNS answers it gets from upstream servers.

```
curl --> dnsmasq -X-> router --> ISP --> ... # NOK
curl --> dnsmasq --> ISP --> ...             # OK
```

Comment: Just an aside I had problems with all websites except google last night after downgrading r8169 driver to r8168 and had to reconfigure IPv4 to automatic DHCP.