# DNS lookups stop working (16.04.6)

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, dns

I have a Ubuntu server (full desktop... don't ask) running 16.04.6 where DNS lookups stop working occasionally. Restarting the `NetworkManager` service resolves the issue, but only temporarily.

I'm able to detect the issue when a log collector stops receiving logs from this system. I access the server via SSH (yes, networking is working) and find that the log shipper service on the system is in a failed state. Attempting to start it fails because it can't resolve the destination server's name. I `dig www.google.com` and it returns "`connection timed out; no servers could be reached`". I restart the `NetworkManager` service, and now DNS lookups work and I can start the log shipper service, resolving the issue (until the next time it occurs).

I have previously commented out `dns=dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` ([How can I disable the DNS that Network Manager uses?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233222/how-can-i-disable-the-dns-that-network-manager-uses)) so that the system doesn't use dnsmasq as a local DNS proxy; however, I have this done on the other servers that perform the same role and don't have this issue on them.

My question is: why is this happening or what are the recommended steps to figure out the cause?